# controller function do not call on button click in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello i am new in angularjs i am working on registration module so i have to call a controller function on button submit this is my code so please help me to call controller function on button click, thank you.

**here is my view**

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-control="regCtrl">
    <h3> Get In Touch!</h3>
    <form role="form"  ng-submit="submit()">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="input1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                <label for="input2">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="submit();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**here is the my controller**

```
app.controller('regCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.submit = function () {
            alert("hello");
            if ($scope.text) {
                $scope.list.push($scope.text);
                $scope.text = '';
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: where is your view?? have you bind the controller with view?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Can you share the view code?

Comment: some basic questions a.) Have you put `ng-app` directive? b.) What is `ng-control`?

Comment: since `$scope.text` and `scope.list` are not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this-

In html file add ng-controller -

```
<div ng-controller="regCtrl">
```

then add form tag with 'ng-submit' attribute like as -

```
 <form name="form" data-ng-submit="submit()" novalidate  role="form">
```

and add normal submit button inside form

```
<button  type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Now it will post your data to controller.

Comment: @dhirendrakumar If it is working fine, Please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your view code should be:

```
<body ng-app="regApp">   
   <div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="regCtrl">
        <h3> Get In Touch!</h3>
        <form role="form"  ng-submit="submit()" novalidate >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label for="input1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label for="input2">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And in your **controller file or app.js** file there should be a **module** created with app name.

```
var app = angular.module( 'regApp', []);

app.controller('regCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.submit = function () {
            alert("hello");
            if ($scope.text) {
                $scope.list.push($scope.text);
                $scope.text = '';
            }
        };
    });
```

I think now it should work !

Answer (score -1):

You have used button type as submit and also using ng-click...

If type is submit then no need to use ng-click directive...

try this one

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Instead of

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: He actually has an ng-click bounded to a function. Suppose this was the issue, then your solution still wouldn't work due to no coupling with a controller function.

Comment: whenever button type is submit and when you click on button ng-submit gets called and he has used ng-submit="submit()".....so submit function will be called.

Comment: I'm not arguing that. There is no controller correctly been assigned to the view, your answer missed that important part and is therefore incorrect.